# Running .NET Core nuget package with native dependencies, library not found

Tags: .net-core, nuget-package

I have these added to my project.

```
<Content Include="../../native/medxdcmtk/lib/libmedxdcmtk.so">
  <PackagePath>runtimes/debian-x64/native/libmedxdcmtk.so</PackagePath>
  <Pack>true</Pack>
</Content>
<Content Include="../../native/dcmtk/lib/libdcmtk.so.10">
  <PackagePath>runtimes/debian-x64/native/libdcmtk.so.10</PackagePath>
  <Pack>true</Pack>
</Content>
<Content Include="../../native/medxdcmtk/lib/libmedxdcmtk.so">
  <PackagePath>runtimes/ubuntu-x64/native/libmedxdcmtk.so</PackagePath>
  <Pack>true</Pack>
</Content>
<Content Include="../../native/dcmtk/lib/libdcmtk.so.10">
  <PackagePath>runtimes/ubuntu-x64/native/libdcmtk.so.10</PackagePath>
  <Pack>true</Pack>
</Content>
```

The resulting package looks like:

[image: nupkg]

When I call a method that uses `PInvoke`, I get this:

```
Error Message:
 System.DllNotFoundException : Unable to load DLL 'libmedxdcmtk': The specified module could not be found.
 (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

This happens on both ubuntu and debian (64bit). If I copy the `.so` files directly to `/usr/lib`, it works.

Why aren't my native assemblies being located?

Comment: Did you make an app to consume this package?

Comment: Yes. A unit test project and a console application. I referenced the package by NuGet (not project). Here is my csproject for the unit test.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/pauldotknopf/e913528d67142a9be867d26ac9ab129e

Comment: Also, can you send me a slack invite for https://aspnetcore.slack.com/

pauldotknopf[at]gmail

Comment: http://tattoocoder.com/asp-net-core-slack-community/